# Magento search is not working

Tags: magento

On my site www.refurbishedprinters.co, I got this error 
Minimum Search query length is 1

The advanced search is giving me this error

You have to specify at least one search term

Please help! it was working a few days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this problem.

Here is the solution:-

The search form method was 'post' in my case. I changed it to 'get' and problem solved :)

When you set the search form method to 'post' then the 'q' parameter will be missing in the URL. 'q' signifies for query. Hence, due to the absence of 'q' query string in URL, the notice/error of 'Minimum query length' occurs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked in the logs?  `/var/system.log` and `/var/exception.log/`?  Please post here any entries of interest.  Also, please check the value in the web admin for `System>Config>Catalog>Catalog Search>Minimal Query Length`

HTH,
JD

Comment: Can some one please help me regarding the add to compare issue after advance search.Because I can not post question here due to question ban I am sharing the link of issue,a video is also attached with that.   http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/297005/    Please help.